# Unable to find debug key in keystore in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, keystore

I'm receiving this error when trying to use a custom debug.keystore in Eclipse for my Android application.

I'm using these commands to generate my keystore:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -alias androidfacebookdebugkey -storepass android -keypass android -keyalg RSA -validity 14000
```

Is there any special way to generate a debug keystore for eclipse? I've never had to do anything in addition to this for any other IDEs.

Comment: Unable to find debug key in keystore

Comment: The default `keystore` that is used by eclipse has a default password `android` and an alias of `androiddebugkey`. My guess is eclipse is trying to sign the debug apk using the default values mentioned above and so it fails..

Comment: Oh I was under the impression that only the password needed to be a certain value. The alias must as well? Create an actual answer and if this works I'll accept.

Comment: And did you place the `keystore` in the right location.
On windows - "C:\Users\{username}\.android"
On mac - "Users/username/.android"

Comment: This is a custom debug keystore. Eclipse asks you where the file is located.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36410/discussion-between-varun-and-josh-elias)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default keystore that is used by eclipse has a default password `android` and an alias of `androiddebugkey`. My guess is eclipse is trying to sign the debug apk using the default values mentioned above and so it fails.

Answer (score 0):

GO to Window >> Preferences >> Android >> Build

It will display default debug.keystore location,MD5 and SHA1 fingerprint